# Would popup blockers stop a URL which pops up only when the user clicked on something?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, popup

I'm currently building a web application that can can track a users actions on a particular website and pop a URL if the user takes certain actions, such as: first click, responding to a question by clicking yes / no, clicking a submit button, or exiting the site.

It is important that these URLs are served to the user and are not blocked by pop-up blockers.  It is my understanding that there are certain exceptions within the major internet browsers that allow pop-ups if they are served based on some user action, rather than serving an unsolicited pop?

Is this true?  How do I design this web application so that it can serve these pops (and not have them blocked).

Comment: The question is way to long, and it almost looks like a job-ad.

Answer (score 0):

In general you get to display one pop-up if you do it in onClick() or similar event handlers.  This is often configurable by the user, however.  For example, in IE users can set their level to High in the pop-up blocker configuration thingy in the Internet Control Panel, which will block everything unless they hold down the override keys while clicking.

Consider using a floating div over top your webpage and populating it with an XHR, the way Stack Overflow does when you vote to close a question.